# Отслеживание и копирование новых записей из одной БД в другую БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, firebird, mariadb

Есть один софт, который пишет в локальную базу Firebird.
По причине корявости архитектуры первичной БД и невозможности вносить в нее изменения и добавлять свои таблицы, возникла необходимость копировать новые записи из БД-1 в свою БД (БД-2) и уже производить все необходимые действия с ней.
Повлиять на работу софта, который пишет в БД-1 не могу, в связи его проприетарности.
Собственно вопрос в чем, как это лучше реализовать? Есть ли готовые решения?
Перегуглил все возможные варианты, но не смог найти нужного. 
БД-1: Firebird
БД-2: MariaDB

Comment: *невозможности вносить в нее изменения и добавлять свои таблицы* По какой причине? неизвестен пароль овнера? софт проверяет структуру? что-то ещё?

Comment: Авторы данного софта - одна около-бюджетная организация. Мы просили у них или приделать апи или дать нам документацию к базе данных, чтобы расширить функционал. Нам ответили, что это нарушает правила лицензии и в случае сбоя в работе мы будем крайние. Поэтому решили просто копировать из нее информацию и работать уже с ней, на отдельной БД.

Comment: А так, база полностью открыта для чтения и записи.

Comment: Если у таблицы есть уникальное ватоинкрементное id, и записи не апдейтятся - то само просто - копировать с id(чужой табл) > max(id-вашей таблицы).

Comment: Ни разу не использовал firebird и слабо представляю что это, но может погуглировать в плане "Firebird replication" или "firebird proxy" ? По первой ссылке есть куча каких-то репликаторов...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал так:

1. в БД-1 добавил бы дополнительную таблицу - список вставленных, но не синхронизированных записей. Заполняется по триггеру на вставку в интересующую таблицу.
2. Написать небольшое приложение (или скрипт), которое по расписанию, скажем раз в 10 минут, подключается к обеим БД, переносит записи, и удаляет из буферной таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

В силу неоднозначности Вашей ситуации и почти полного отсутствия подробностей, сложно посоветовать точное решение. Но, в принципе все варианты варианты сводятся к следующим:

- Делать выгрузку из FB и далее грузить в MySQL с помощью специализированного софта (есть готовые, но они часто платные);
- Делать то же самое на основе собственного ПО (больше гибкость и возможность полной автоматизации процесса);
- Создать в Firebird свою БД и грузить в неё данные и 1й БД распределённым запросом (свой софт придётся адаптировать под Firebird).

Что для Вас проще, удобнее и эффективнее уже смотрите сами.

Comment: А какие подробности интересуют? Структура?

Comment: Какова цель копирования? Пишете новый софт?  Дорабатываете уже существующий? Каковы требования к актуальности БД?

Comment: Да, пишем новый софт. В базу стекаются события с пожарной сигнализации, которая установлена на ~2к объектов. Хочу это все объединить с внутренней базой предприятия. И уже там накручивать все новые фичи. Разрабы этого ПО придерживаются принципа "работает и ладно". Добиться от них внедрения новых функций не получается. Поэтому приходится городить свое.

Comment: Тогда  лучше второй или третий вариант. Во всяком случае, я бы сделал именно так.

Comment: А вы не знаете, можно ли написать триггер, который будет при insert в БД-1 копировать это в БД-2?

Comment: Такое теоретически возможно, если у Вас обе БД Firebird (по сути это один из способов реализации 3 способа). Если Ваша БД будет в формате другой СУБД этот фокус вряд ли прокатит (очень сильно сомневаюсь, что Firebird умеет интегрироваться с другим СУБД).